# Create function to init model schema

Tags: javascript, prototype, descriptor

Recently, at an interview, I was given a task that I could not solve. I would be very happy if someone helps to figure out how to solve it!

"Create a function to init model schema. Add method to define relation one-to-one, one-to-many. Model fields should have types. Raise an error when type is not corresponding."

```
const Card = Model({
  number: Number,
  pin: String
});


const Post = Model({
  title: String,
  description: String
});


const User = Model({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  posts: Model.hasMany(Post),
  card: Model.hasOne(Card),
});


User.prototype.hasCard = function() {
  return !!this.card;
};

const user = new User({
  name: 'User',
  age: 25,
  posts: [{
    title: 'Post1',
    description: 'Post description'
  }],
  card: null
});

console.log(user.hasCard()); //false
```